# Elasticsearch - Relevancy of search terms

Tags: elasticsearch, search, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-dsl

How do you tell Elasticsearch that one full text field should be ***less relevant*** than other full text fields?

Suppose I have:

```
"query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": {
                    "query_string": {
                        "fields": ["my_id", "title^2", "intro", "body1", "body2", "body3", "footer"],
                        "default_operator": "AND",
                        "query": "some search query"
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

I want *footer* to be treated as less relevant than the others. What is the best approach to that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A boost value between 0 and 1.0 [decreases the relevance score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-top-level-params). So for example:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "query_string": {
          "fields": [
            ...
            "footer^0.5"
          ],
          ...
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

should do the trick.

Comment: @Joe_Sorocin Thanks! I saw the `^2` marker in my original query beside title. I presume that will treat `title` matches as being more relevant? But your answers says between 0 and 1, so I was just confused. Thanks

Comment: That’s right — the roof sign means boost and 2 means what you assumed 

Comment: Hey btw I'm releasing my elasticsearch handbook full of clarifications like this soon -- you can [let me know](https://jozefsorocin.typeform.com/to/XeQRxdwV) what topics interest you and I'll let you know when it's out!

Comment: Perfect! I would be interested. I will fill that out with some topics of interest. Just so I am aware, is there a rule of thumb that I should keep boosted values between 0 and 1.0 for example? This way, we don't end up with overly inflated values?

Comment: Sounds good! Scores between 0 are 1.0 are perfectly fine -- they simply decrease the relevance. Now, although ES supports index-time boosting, the best practice is to assign boosts at search-time -- and you're already doing that, so all good. Just experiment with the boosting and see what suits your use case best.

Comment: @Ricky -- don't forget to sign up [here](https://jozefsorocin.typeform.com/to/XeQRxdwV) 